# Is there an alternative to ffmpeg so that my flutter app can render videos via the shared ffi library?

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, video, ffmpeg

I want to build a video editor app with flutter, but I have problems rendering, I want to use ffmpeg but it requires exec command is there a video rendering library from image + merge video / audio into one using shared library in linux?

/ ffmpeg can be compiled into a shared library?

Answer (score 0):

For ffmpeg compilation, you can find more here https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide and compile it as a shared library.

As for an alternative, i would suggest GStreamer https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/